# Equivalence classes and Cardinal number

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

For groups $A,B,C,D$, if $C\sim D,\ A\sim B$ and $A\cap C=B\cap D=\emptyset$, Prove that $A\cup C\sim B\cup D$.

I don't know how to approach this question. i thought about dividing the problem into cases. Would like some guidance. Thanks

Comment: What does the notation $C\sim D$ mean?

Comment: Read expressions like $A\sim B$ as: "a bijection $f:A\to B$ exists". That makes clear how to solve this.

Comment: @Desperado $|C|=|D|$, but both groups can be infinite.

Comment: Well, $|A\cup C|=|A|+|C|$. Can you take from here?

Comment: Start by reading this: https://karagila.org/2015/how-to-solve-your-problems/

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $f:A\to B$ and $g:C\to D$ be bijections and identify these functions with their graphs.

Then what can be said of $f\cup g$ under the given conditions?

Comment: sorry but I can't see how's that helping me

Comment: $f\cup g$ can be recognized as a bijection $A\cup C\to B\cup D$ and the existence of such a bijection is exactly what you need.